# merging outlook calendars

Tags: exchange, outlook, outlook-2003

Our company has acquired another and as a result, their employees. We didn't get any of their equipment, but they did give us all of their users' outlook pst files. I was able to open that pst file in each user's copy of outlook. The imported pst file acts as another account or set of personal folders, so each user has 2 sets of mail folders, 2 calendars, 2 task lists etc. I want to merge these all into the single default mailbox folders.

When saving the events/tasks it says that the reminders won't fire because they are not in the calendar or tasks folder - they ARE synchronized in exchange though.

I found out about the outlook switch /resetfolders but the documentation on that switch is sparse with what it actually does, and this is not really within my realm of competency to be confident that her mailbox won't be adversely affected. Not only that, but each of these new users (though it was a small company) has to maintain 2 of everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than open the PST you need to look at Outlook's import/export feature.  Alternatively do exmerge from the server side.

Comment: I second. Import the pst file into the current mailbox for each user.

Comment: I'll give this a shot on Monday and let you know.